# How to control the div within the div?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Hover the mouse on the blue box; the blue box will rotate 170 degrees but it overlaps the parent `div`. I want to rotate the blue box without overlapping the parent `div`.

```css
.box {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:red;
}
.box_inside {
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:blue;
  transition:all 0.7s linear;
}
.box_inside:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(170deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
  transform: rotate(170deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_inside"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not overlapping the parent div (they are the same width/height so they will overlap)?

Comment: *Umm,* the geometry is up to you!  CSS doesn't think about objects "containing" other objects: they have various Z-order positions but this is not a full-blown, hierarchical, graphic-object model.  If you want to make sure that the object doesn't overlap another, *you* must set the size and position of the respective objects accordingly.

Comment: Hi i mean when it rotates it should rotate within the red div . But in this program you will see that when it rotates the corner of blue box overlaps the red div (parent div).

Comment: Might remark that the animation is *horrendously* annoying.,. I hope that this isn't some standalone main feature of a site...

Comment: @cybermonkey This is not for any site . I just wanted to learn and i learnt. :)

Comment: @HarwinderSingh You might want to look into JavaScript after you learn CSS, I've just started learning and it's really good (although I question some of the syntax).

Comment: @cybermonkey Yeah i learn javascript too. :)

Comment: @HarwinderSingh I submitted an edit to increase the readability & visibility of your question. You may want to mark the answer below as accepted, to make others know that your issue has been solved.

Comment: @cybermonkey I tried to mark the Mosh's answer as correct answer but i got a message that i couldn't do it before 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you looking for `overflow:hidden` for the parent. You need to add `position:relative` too.

```css
.box {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.box_inside {
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background:blue;
  transition:all 0.7s linear;
}
.box_inside:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(170deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
  transform: rotate(170deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box_inside"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mosh! Awesome :)

Comment: My pleasure :) If it helps you, please accept the answer so it will help to other people.